# Obtener el color de fondo de un control JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Quiero leer el color de fondo de un control desde código javaFX para luego aplicarle una transparencia. He estado buscando información pero no me aclaro. No hay ningún método `getBackgroundColor()` pero si `getBackground()` aunque ando perdidísimo ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Podía ser buena opción especificar a que control deseas aplicar la transparencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perdón por la respuesta kilométrica, tenía mucho tiempo que no usaba JavaFX y por lo mismo investigué un poco más a fondo.

Respuesta corta:

Puedes obtener los colores usados apra el fondo a aprtir de método `getBackground`, que a su vez dentro tiene una lista de los colores usados, y a menos que estés usando un gradiente o algo similar, el primer fill debería de ser el color único de fondo de tu objeto.

```
Color color = (Color) boton.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getFill();
System.out.println("color:"+color);
```

Respuesta larga:

Es importante que diferencies entre el color que se pone programáticamente y el que se pone desde estilo [javafx-css](/questions/tagged/javafx-css), ya que los estilos tienen mayor preferencia que los colores de fondo normales y pueden producir errores sutiles, que pueden o no obrar a nuestro favor y yo sugiero siempre usar colores programáticos en vez de estilos css de javafx.

Veamos un ejemplo simple, si tienes un fxml con un botón así:

```
<Button fx:id="btnrojillo" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" text="Button" />
```

y en tu handles de botón poes algo como:

```
@FXML
protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String style = btnrojillo.getStyle();

    System.out.println(style);
    btnrojillo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    String colorDesdeEstilo = style.replaceAll(".*(-fx-background-color:\\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)).*", "$2");


    System.out.println("color detectado desde hoja de estilos:" +
            colorDesdeEstilo
    );

    Color color = (Color) btnrojillo.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getFill();
    System.out.println("color detectado desde configuración de componente:" + color.toString().substring(2));
}
```

La primera vez que lo corras obtendrás un muy horrible NPE (No es lo que piensas picarón ;) ) como este:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at swinginterop.Model.handleSubmitButtonAction

Ahora si le metemos un selector de colores a nuestro [fxml](/questions/tagged/fxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="swinginterop.Model">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="36.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="266.0" prefWidth="258.0">
         <children>
            <ColorPicker fx:id="colorchooser" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="40.0" onAction="#handleColorSelectedAction" />
            <Button fx:id="btnrojillo" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" text="Button" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Y en nuestro código Java

```
@FXML
protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String style = btnrojillo.getStyle();

    System.out.println(style);
    String colorDesdeEstilo = style.replaceAll(".*(-fx-background-color:\\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)).*", "$2");


    System.out.println("color detectado desde hoja de estilos:" +
            colorDesdeEstilo
    );

    Color color = (Color) btnrojillo.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getFill();
    System.out.println("color detectado desde configuración de componente:" + color.toString().substring(2));
}


@FXML
protected void handleColorSelectedAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String value = colorchooser.getValue().toString().substring(2);
    btnrojillo.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                    colorchooser.getValue(), null, null
            )
            )
    );

}
```

Observaremos que el color solamente cambia temporalmente y regresa al color definido en el estilo.

Por ello es que te recomiendo si necesitas modificar el color hacerlo directamente en la propiedad style.

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="swinginterop.Model">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="36.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="266.0" prefWidth="258.0">
         <children>
            <ColorPicker fx:id="colorchooser" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="40.0" onAction="#handleColorSelectedAction" />
            <Button fx:id="btnrojillo" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" text="Button" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Java:

```
package swinginterop;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Model extends Application {
    @FXML
    private Button btnrojillo;

    @FXML
    ColorPicker colorchooser;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FórmulasGrasa.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String style = btnrojillo.getStyle();

        System.out.println(style);
        String colorDesdeEstilo = style.replaceAll(".*(-fx-background-color:\\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)).*", "$2");


        System.out.println("color detectado desde hoja de estilos:" +
                colorDesdeEstilo
        );

        Color color = (Color) btnrojillo.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getFill();
        System.out.println("color detectado desde configuración de componente:" + color.toString().substring(2));
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handleColorSelectedAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String value = colorchooser.getValue().toString().substring(2);
        Paint red = Paint.valueOf(value);
        btnrojillo.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                        colorchooser.getValue(), null, null
                )
                )
        );

        btnrojillo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #"+value+';');

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Si de casualidad ocupas hacer binding al color te recomiendo leer [esta pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851893/javafx-how-to-get-background-color-of-tab-button-etc).

Si ocupas transparencia puedes probar en el css con algo como:

```
-fx-background-color: none;
```

o si estás modificando directamente el Background desde código poniendo los fills en nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Mira si esto es lo que necesitas en este link: [ventana con bordes sombreados](http://acodigo.blogspot.com.co/2015/03/ventana-javafx-con-bordes-sombreados.html)

La parte que debe mirar con atención es:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

y

```
// Establecer el color de relleno del Scene a transparente
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no me sirve. Lo que pretendo es saber el color que tiene un control. Establecer un color lo hago por ejemplo así: control.setStyle ("-fx-background-color: red;");